# BufferedImage to Bytes Java

Tags: java, image-processing, arrays

I am trying to get the bytearray from a bufferedImage but the length of my ByteArrayOutputstream is always zero and I get no bytes. This is what I am doing

any ideas why this is not working

```
BufferedImage scaledPicture = .....

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
ImageIO.write(scaledPicture, extension, baos);
baos.flush();
byte[] toByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
return toByteArray;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the return value of `ImageIO.write`? Does `ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName` with your extension return at least 1 `ImageWriter`? If not, then the format may not be supported.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. It is returning false, so no writer found. Since the image is uploaded from the browser, how do i determine the format or how do i specify a format in the ImageIO.write call?

Comment: @Farouk Alhassan I would try using `ImagIO.getImageWritersBySuffix` and see if you get any `ImageWriter`s back for it. If so you can easily use those with their `write` method to write your `RenderedImage`. The method you're using at the moment is just a simple wrapper around that anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. Fixed it after a day. was purely because an old unit untested code was calculating the file extension wrongly, returning .jpeg instead of jpeg hence a wasted day! Lessons learnt. Anyway, i know more today than yesterday so am grateful. tx

Comment: Great, glad you found the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Does the 'ImageIO.write(...)' call return true?  If no, the JVM might be failing to find a writer of the appropriate format.